# Strange error: label 'loopend' used but not defined, expected unqualified-id before " if " (same error for "goto" and " '}' token "

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is my code. I'm not sure why these errors are appearing, and I looked as thoroughly as possible.

I know that the first error seems to happen because my "loopend:" label
at the end of my program seems to be too far away or something. Is that a probable reason?

As for the rest, I have no idea why they pop up.

It appears to be a problem after the " if(Choice=="OSI") " area.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream pswdchk ("OSIUser.setting");
    string Password[5];
    string Passload[5];
    string NormPass;
    string tocmd;
    int Chickenvar=0;
    int CMD=1;
    string Choice;
    string Title;
    string style = "-";
    string Bdr = "";
    string Columnten = "";
    string Columnten1 = "";
    string Columnten2 = "";
    string WaitColumn = "";
    std::string opt1;
    std::string opt2;
    std::string opt3;
    std::string opt4;
    std::string opt5;
    std::string opt6;
loop:
    system("color 3b");
    if(CMD==0) {
    cout <<"Invalid Command.\n\n>";
}
if (Chickenvar==1) {
    cout << "\n\nChicken 'style' to chicken a stylish chicken test. Chicken 'exit' to chicken\nprogram. KFC is love, KFC is life.\n\nCHICKEN GOES HERE>";
}
    if (CMD==1) {
    if (Chickenvar==0) {
        cout <<"OBCLS Version 0.3\nType exit to quit.\n\n>";
    }
}
CMD=0;

cin >>Choice;
if(Choice=="exit") {
goto loopend;
}
if(Choice=="style") {
    using namespace std; //It seems I need it here too?
    CMD=1;
    system("color 2e");
    system("CLS");
    opt1 = "\n1:                     Style 1";
    opt2 = "\n2:                     Style 2";
    opt3 = "\n3:                     Style 3";
    opt4 = "\n4:                     Style 4";
    opt5 = "\n5:                     Style 5";
    opt6 = "\n6:                    No Style";
    std::cout << "Hello!" << "\nThis is a test of the OIS Styling       System..." << "\nChoose a style:" << opt1 << opt2 << opt3 << opt4 << opt5 << opt6 <<"\n";
    std::string Choice = "";
ChoiceRetry:

    cout << "\n>";
    cin >> Choice;
    if (Choice == "6") {
        cout << "Viewing styleless window:\n\n";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    if (Choice == "1") {
        Columnten = "----------";
        Columnten1 = " ----------";
        Columnten2 = "---------";
        Bdr = "| ";
        WaitColumn = " ---------PRESS--ENTER--------";
        style = "1";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }
    if (Choice == "2") {
        Columnten = "          ";
        Columnten1 = "o         ";
        Columnten2 = "          o";
        Bdr = " ";
        WaitColumn = "o         PRESS  ENTER        o";
        style = "2";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }
    if (Choice == "3") {
        Columnten = "//////////";
        Columnten1 = "//////////";
        Columnten2 = "//////////";
        Bdr = "/";
        WaitColumn = "/////////PRESS  ENTER/////////";
        style = "3";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }
    if (Choice == "4") {
        Columnten = "==========";
        Columnten1 = "==========";
        Columnten2 = "==========";
        Bdr = "=";
        WaitColumn = "=========PRESS==ENTER=========";
        style = "4";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }
    if (Choice == "5") {
        Columnten = "##########";
        Columnten1 = " #########";
        Columnten2 = "######### ";
        Bdr = "#";
        WaitColumn = " ####### PRESS  ENTER ####### ";
        style = "5";
        goto ChoiceYes;
    }
    cout << "Invalid input.";
    goto ChoiceRetry;
ChoiceYes:
    Title = " EXAMPLE: ";
    //string ColumnTitle = Columnten1, Title, Columnten2;(USE COUT)
    //string Column = Columnten1, Columnten, Columnten2; (USE COUT)
    cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
    string TYPE = "This is an example window   ";
    cout << Bdr<< TYPE<< Bdr<< "\n";
    TYPE = "         for style ";
    cout << Bdr<< TYPE<< style ;
    TYPE = ".       ";
    cout << TYPE<<Bdr<< "\n";
    cout << WaitColumn;





    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    std::cin.get();
    system("CLS");
}
if (Choice=="Chicken"){
    if(Chickenvar==0){  
    Chickenvar=1;
    cout<<"Chicken Mode Enabled";
    goto Chicken_toggle_end;
}
    if(Chickenvar==1){
    Chickenvar=0;
    goto Chicken_toggle_end;
    cout<<"Chicken Mode Disabled";
    }
    Chicken_toggle_end:
    CMD=1;
    goto loop;
}
if (Choice=="cmd"){
    system("CLS");
    system("color 6e");
    cout <<"This will not work on systems with a disabled command prompt\n\n";
    system("cmd");
    CMD=1;
    system("CLS");
}
if (Choice=="help"){
    CMD=1;
    cout<<"To run commands using CMD, type 'cmd'.\nTo test the styling system, type 'style'.\nTo exit the program, type 'exit'.\nTo run the GUI, type 'OSI'.\n\n";

}
if (Choice=="OSI"){
    Styleloop:
    system("CLS");
    system("color 2a");
    cout<<"\n\nChoose the system style.\nEnter 1-5, 6 for no style:";
    cin>>Choice;
    if (Choice == "1") {
        Columnten = "----------";
        Columnten1 = " ----------";
        Columnten2 = "---------";
        Bdr = "| ";
        WaitColumn = "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ";
        style = "1";
        goto Styleend;
    }
    if (Choice == "2") {
        Columnten = "          ";
        Columnten1 = "o         ";
        Columnten2 = "          o";
        Bdr = " ";
        WaitColumn = "o                                               o";
        style = "2";
        goto Styleend;
    }
    if (Choice == "3") {
        Columnten = "//////////";
        Columnten1 = "//////////";
        Columnten2 = "//////////";
        Bdr = "/";
        WaitColumn = "//////////////////     ++++     ////////////////";
        style = "3";
        goto Styleend;
    }
    if (Choice == "4") {
        Columnten = "==========";
        Columnten1 = "==========";
        Columnten2 = "==========";
        Bdr = "=";
        WaitColumn = "================================================";
        style = "4";
        goto Styleend;
    }
    if (Choice == "5") {
        Columnten = "##########";
        Columnten1 = " #########";
        Columnten2 = "######### ";
        Bdr = "#";
        WaitColumn = " ############################################## ";
        style = "5";
        goto Styleend;
    }
    if (Choice == "6") {
    string style = "-";
    string Bdr = " ";
    string Columnten = " ";
    string Columnten1 = " ";
    string Columnten2 = " ";
    string WaitColumn = " ";
    goto Styleend;
    }
    goto Styleloop;
    Styleend:
    OSImainloop:
system("CLS");  
opt1 = "                                              ";
opt2 = "                 OSI v0.2.3                   ";
opt3 = "                                              ";
opt4 = "          1:                    Exit          ";
opt5 = "          2:                  Log in          ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  Welcome to OSI GUI v1.0   ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter A Number:";


cin>>Choice;
if(Choice=="1"){
    goto exitmain;
}
if (Choice=="2"){
    goto OSImainloopbreak;
}
goto OSImainloop;
OSImainloopbreak:
    OSIlogloop:
system("CLS");  
opt1 = " Type exit to go back                         ";
opt2 = "                                              ";
opt3 = "                                              ";
opt4 = "             - ENTER PASSWORD -               ";
opt5 = "       Type 'new' to create a new user.       ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter Password:";
cin >>Choice;
if (Choice=="exit"){
goto OSImainloop;
}
if (Choice=="new"){
newuser:
system("CLS;");
opt1 = " Type exit to abort operation                 ";
opt2 = "                                              ";    
opt3 = "          Please enter a password             ";
opt4 = "             for your new user.               ";
opt5 = "                   .....                      ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter Your New Password:";
cin >>NormPass;
if (NormPass=="new"){
system("CLS;");
opt1 = "                                              ";    
opt2 = "       Sorry. This password is reserved       ";
opt3 = "            for the new user command.         ";
opt4 = "                                              ";
opt5 = "                -Press Enter-                 ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="           -Error-          ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\n";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
std::cin.get();
goto newuser;
}
if (NormPass=="exit"){
    goto OSImainloopbreak;
}
PassGenRetry:
ofstream passgen;
passgen.open ("OSIUser.setting");
if (passgen.is_open()) {
    passgen <<NormPass;
}
else {
filebadloop:
system("CLS;");
opt1 = "                                              ";
opt2 = "          The file 'Users.passwf' did         ";
opt3 = "             not open successfully.           ";
opt4 = "         A new user cannot be created.        ";
opt5 = "            1=Retry        2=Abort            ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter A Number:";
cin>>Choice;
if (Choice=="1"){
    cout<<"Press Enter to attempt to open 'Users.passwf' again...";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    std::cin.get();
    goto PassGenRetry;
}
if (Choice=="2"){
    goto OSImainloopbreak;
}
goto filebadloop;
}
system("CLS;");
opt1 = "                                              ";
opt2 = "   Password has been successsfully installed. ";
opt3 = "          Press Enter to continue.            ";
opt4 = "                                              ";
opt5 = "                    .....                     ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\n";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
std::cin.get();
goto OSIlogloop;
}
Pswdchkloop:
if (pswdchk.is_open()){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

    pswdchk>>Password[i];
}
}
else {
chkbadloop:
system("CLS;");
opt1 = "                                              ";
opt2 = "          The file 'Users.passwf' did         ";
opt3 = "             not open successfully.           ";
opt4 = "           Passwords failed to load.          ";
opt5 = "            1=Retry        2=Abort            ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter A Number:";
cin>>Choice;
if (Choice=="1"){
    cout<<"Press Enter to attempt to open 'Users.passwf' again...";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    std::cin.get();
    goto Pswdchkloop;
}
if (Choice=="2"){
    goto OSImainloop;
}
goto chkbadloop;
} 
if (Choice==Password[0]){

    goto OSIlogloopbreak;
}
goto OSIlogloop;
OSIlogloopbreak:
if (Chickenvar==1){
cout<<"ADMIN ENABLED\n\nPress Enter";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
std::cin.get();
}
else {
    cout<<"User initiated.\n\nPress Enter"; 
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
    std::cin.get();
}
loopmainmenu:
system("color 3b");
system("CLS;");
if (Chickenvar==1){
opt1 = " Welcome Admin                         v0.2.3 ";
}
else {
    opt1 = " Welcome User                          v0.2.3 ";
}
opt2 = "                 Options:                     ";
opt3 = "-Programs                                     ";
opt4 = "-Options                                      ";
opt5 = "-About                                        ";
opt6 = "-Exit                                         ";
Title="         - Welcome -        ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nChoose an option:";
cin>>Choice;
for(unsigned int n = 0; n < Choice.length(); ++n) {
Choice[n] = tolower(Choice[n]);
}
if (Choice=="exit"){
goto OSImainloop;
}
if (Choice=="about"){
system("CLS;");
system("color 7e");
opt1 = "           OSI GUI and Command Shell          ";
opt2 = "                   System                     ";
opt3 = "                                              ";
opt4 = "              By Olivier Poirier              ";
opt5 = "                                              ";
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="         - About -          ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\n";
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
std::cin.get();
}
if (Choice=="programs"){
prgmloop:
system("color 2a");
system("CLS");  
opt1 = "                                              ";
if (Chickenvar==1){
opt1 = "                     - Hidden Items Revealed -";
}
opt2 = "-Word                                         ";
opt3 = "-Text Adventure                               ";
opt4 = "-Exit                                         ";
opt5 = "                                              ";
if (Chickenvar==1){
opt5 = "-Special Documents                            ";
}
opt6 = "                                              ";
Title="  User Login Access System  ";
cout << Columnten1<< Title<< Columnten2 << "\n" ;
cout<< Bdr<< opt1<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt2<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt3<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt4<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt5<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<< Bdr<< opt6<< Bdr<<"\n";
cout<<WaitColumn<<"\nEnter Password:";
cin >>Choice;
for(unsigned int n = 0; n < Choice.length(); ++n) {
Choice[n] = tolower(Choice[n]);
}
if (Choice=="exit"){
goto loopmainmenu;

}

}
}
goto loopmainmenu;
exitmain:
CMD=1;
system("CLS");
}
if (Choice=="clear"){
CMD=1;
system("CLS");
}   

goto loop;
loopend:
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you could be off with closing braces and that your label isn't actually in an executable part of your file. The lack of formatting doesn't help figure this out for sure. Is there a particular reason why you've opted for such a heavy use of goto statements? I think you'd be much better served if you broke this program up into functions so that others can better understand your code. In the the process you may even figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Olivier Poirier You should probably reformat your code so it's reasonably readable.  The answer may even present itself

Comment: [Structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) has been well known to be a good idea for half a century. Unless you're deliberately exploring the mess you end up with if you don't use it, consider embracing the 1970's and learn about loops and functions.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code into a new source file in VS2013 and then on Edit menu, Advanced -> Format Document. This tidies up the indenting and layout of your code. It then becomes visually clear that you have closed off your `int main()` function leaving this code following it which the compiler is rejecting. Your label `loopend` is outside the function so is not visible inside it.

```
int main() {
    ... ... ...
    goto loopmainmenu;
exitmain:
    CMD = 1;
    system("CLS");
}
```

then following this:

```
if (Choice == "clear"){
    CMD = 1;
    system("CLS");
}

goto loop;
loopend:
return 0;
}
```

You need to move this code back into `int main()`.

As a suggestion, you should replace all those `goto` statements.

```
if (Choice == "Chicken"){
    if (Chickenvar == 0){
        Chickenvar = 1;
        cout << "Chicken Mode Enabled";
        goto Chicken_toggle_end;
    }
    if (Chickenvar == 1){
        Chickenvar = 0;
        goto Chicken_toggle_end;
        cout << "Chicken Mode Disabled";
    }
Chicken_toggle_end:
    CMD = 1;
    goto loop;
}
```

becomes

```
if (Choice == "Chicken"){
    if (Chickenvar == 0){
        Chickenvar = 1;
        cout << "Chicken Mode Enabled";
    }
    if (Chickenvar == 1){
        Chickenvar = 0;
        cout << "Chicken Mode Disabled";
    }
    CMD = 1;
}
```

and rather than `goto loop` put the logic inside a `while` loop. `Goto` logic is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `}`s in your program, which means that everything including and after `if (Choice=="clear"){` is outside `main`.

This would be clearer if you indented your code and even clearer if you used functions to split up your code and didn't use so many gotos.